Boole and Exclusions give diffferent NIntegrate results when handling singularities
My Mathematica version is 13.2 and 14.1 for Windows.
I find Boole[] and  Exclusions -> may get different result if the integrand is complex.
This is my Code 1 (using Boole[] handle singularities)：
NIntegrate[Boole[1 + p^2 - 2 p*\[Eta] > 0] Boole[10^11 >= Sqrt[1 - 2 p*\[Eta] + p^2] >= 10^-14] Boole[1 >= Sqrt[1 - 2 p*\[Eta] + p^2]*n >= 10^-15] Boole[ 1 >= Sqrt[1 - 2 p*\[Eta] + p^2]*z >= 10^-15] (1/Sqrt[ 1 + p^2 - 2 p*\[Eta]]), {\[Eta], -1, 1}, {p, 10^-14, 10^11}, {x, 10^-15/p, 1/p}, {m, 10^-15/p, 1/p}, {n, x, 1/p}, {z, m, 1/p}, AccuracyGoal -> Infinity, PrecisionGoal -> 5](*Return 0.456126*)

This is my Code 2 (using Exclusions -> handle singularities)：
NIntegrate[Boole[10^11 >= Sqrt[1 - 2 p*\[Eta] + p^2] >= 10^-14] Boole[1 >= Sqrt[1 - 2 p*\[Eta] + p^2]*n >= 10^-15] Boole[1 >= Sqrt[1 - 2 p*\[Eta] + p^2]*z >= 10^-15] (1/Sqrt[ 1 + p^2 - 2 p*\[Eta]]), {\[Eta], -1, 1}, {p, 10^-14, 10^11}, {x,   10^-15/p, 1/p}, {m, 10^-15/p, 1/p}, {n, x, 1/p}, {z, m, 1/p},  AccuracyGoal -> Infinity, PrecisionGoal -> 5,  Exclusions -> 1 + p^2 - 2 p*\[Eta] == 0]
(*Return 1.1917 with 0.72error and NIntegrate::eincr,NIntegrate::slwcon)


To avoid these and get a low error, I increase WorkingPrecision, MaxErrorIncreases, MinRecursion, MaxRecursion below:
NIntegrate[Boole[10^11 >= Sqrt[1 - 2 p*\[Eta] + p^2] >= 10^-14] Boole[ 1 >= Sqrt[1 - 2 p*\[Eta] + p^2]*n >= 10^-15] Boole[1 >= Sqrt[1 - 2 p*\[Eta] + p^2]*z >= 10^-15] (1/Sqrt[ 1 + p^2 - 2 p*\[Eta]]), {\[Eta], -1, 1}, {p, 10^-14, 10^11}, {x, 10^-15/p, 1/p}, {m, 10^-15/p, 1/p}, {n, x, 1/p}, {z, m, 1/p},  Method -> {"GlobalAdaptive", "MaxErrorIncreases" -> 10000}, AccuracyGoal -> Infinity, PrecisionGoal -> 12,  WorkingPrecision -> 200, Exclusions -> 1 + p^2 - 2 p*\[Eta] == 0,  MaxRecursion -> 200, MinRecursion -> 100]
(*Return0.059 and0.0025 error NIntegrate::eincr,NIntegrate::slwcon*)


I don't know which one is correct and why the other is wrong, how to change NIntegrate options to silence NIntegrate::eincr, NIntegrate::slwcon in my code 2. I checked some simple integrand examples, both methods (Boole[] and Exclusions ->) coincide each other.
Thank you!

Welcome to Mathematica StackExchange! Please edit the question and specify the version of Mathematica you are using. For example, in version 14.1, I get the first two results the same and without any error messages, so it might be that this has been already fixed ...

On my machine code 1 and code 2 return the same result 0.456126. My version is  "14.1.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (July 16, 2024)"

Sorry,My Mathematica version is 13.2 and 14.1 for Windows,both give same result as the question above.Code 2 Return 1.1917 with 0.72error and NIntegrate::eincr,NIntegrate::slwcon.

@Domen: very glad to receive your suggestion ,it makes me notice Mathematica version difference, so I add a picture and version information in my question. I checked my version same as you ,but different result ,so strange!

@Jie Zhu : very glad to receive your suggestion ,it makes me notice Mathematica version difference, so I add a picture and version information in my question. I checked my version  "14.1.0 for Windows (64-bit) (July 16, 2024)"

@ScrippsMoore, oh, but you didn't include the same code that you are using! You have a separate function f defined! This likely affects the computation. Please edit the question and include the actual code you are running.

@Domen Thank you for your reminder. I run the original expressions and put the result (Image form) in my question.
